# Google VR Web Error on init

Tags: google-vr

I am following the example from the documentation on https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web. Here is my code:

```
 <head>
<script src="vrview.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
function onVrViewLoad() {
 var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
 video: 'http://localhost/360/spa360injected.mp4',
 is_stereo: true,
 width:'640',
 height:'480'
});
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="vrview"></div>
</body>



</html>
```

I get the error

```
vrview.min.js:1 GET http://localhost/index.html?video=http://localhost/360/spa360injected.mp4&is_stereo=true& 404 (Not Found)
```

This should be a plug and play example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. It worked fine when creating a test project but when I use in my app I get your same message.